# Importing Leaflet-Library in a OpenUI5-App

Tags: javascript, xml, web, sapui5, openstreetmap

so what am I trying to do?
I am creating an OpenUI5 webapp, the purpose of which is to route users in a given area.
For this I should use OpenStreetMap, and after a few minutes of research I came across the Leaflet-Library. So I want import the library and use it to show the given area.

My problem is that all the tutorials i came across so far just tell me how to do this with html, sadly I only have xml views.

Has anyone a tutorial for this rather specific scenario?

Comment: Hi there, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: If you're building an OpenUI5 app, isn't it usually a stand-alone app? Just wondering why it's not possible with html..

Comment: The problem i am facing is that i have an xml-view in which i want to use the map from leaflet library. And sadly i don´t have clue on how to implement the map in the view. Because all of the Tutorials i came across work with plain html, and just declare a <div> and then set the map into this div. But as far as I know there is no <div> in sap.m. 
Might have been poor wording in my initial question

Answer (score -1):

You can add the library you want to use in your Openui5 application's index.html file, inside head tag next to ui5 bootstraping, like this:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.77.2/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3" data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "project": "./"
        }' data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
    data-sap-ui-async="true" data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted">
    </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin="" />
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
```

I don't know the library you want to use, but if you need to create any HTML elements you can use the sap.ui.core.HTML class.

This should work!

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately, this answer is based on the assumption that the question author has access to the HTML document which doesn't seem to be true. From the question: "My problem is that all the tutorials i came across so far just tell me how to do this with html, sadly I only have xml views."

Comment: It has only views in xml, however Openui5 needs an HTML file to load all the dependencies of ui5, it can add any other javascript library next to the openui5 startup.

Comment: I was wondering about it too (hence my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030702/importing-leaflet-library-in-a-openui5-app/63041604?noredirect=1#comment111482554_63030702) in the question). But for now, it is clear that the question author doesn't want an html solution.

Comment: Thank you, this would work but wasn´t my prefered solution. I now decided on installing it via package.json which seems to have worked fine.

Comment: @Nik.not.thicc If you've found a solution, consider to add an answer and accepting it to let others know that the issue is resolved by now.